# How I can pass over a field validation in a serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Location model and I need to create a Location without specifying a user, if user in empty then the user will be placed in request.user in the viewset.

This is my model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializer:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def is_valid(self):
        if not 'user' in self.init_data:
            # avoid this validation.. I manage this in the viewset
            pass

        return not self.errors

    class Meta:
        model = Location
```

and viewset

```
class LocationViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows location to be created or viewed.
    """
    model = Location
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, JSONPRenderer)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.locations.filter(deleted=False)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.pre_save(serializer.object)
            if not self.object.user:
                self.object.user = request.user
            self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
            self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                            headers=headers)
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `required=False` in serializer:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.RelatedField(required=False)
```

**EDIT**

Also you can simplify your viewset with:

```
class LocationViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def pre_save(self, obj):
        if obj.user_id is None:
            obj.user = self.request.user
```

This avoid copying code from DRF core.

Comment: work well but I have to change the pre_save method by: 
try:
  obj.user
except User.DoesNotExist:
  obj.user = self.request.user
If you can please edit your answer to mark as correct
Thanks for your help

Comment: can you try `if obj.user_id is None: obj.user = self.request.user` in pre_save and tell me if you still get the exception ? I would prefer this solution than the try/except block

Comment: yes, ``if obj.user_id is None: obj.user = self.request.user`` works